# Which Silverlight ArcGIS SDK link to use?

Tags: silverlight, bing-maps, arcgis, deepzoom

I am confused as to which ArcGIS SDK I should use for developing a ArcGIS map-based Silverlight application.

I just signed up and downloaded the SDK isntaller from ESRI:
http://help.arcgis.com/en/webapi/silverlight/index.html

But then i noticed that Codeplex has their own SDK:
http://esrisilverlight.codeplex.com/

Which SDK should I be using? Or are both the same (i doubt this)?

*** UPDATED ***

Or should I just go with the Silverlight Bing Maps API???

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Codeplex project depends on the ESRI SDK, it is not standalone. It adds additional functionality to what you'll get out of the box in the SDK.

Your link: http://help.arcgis.com/en/webapi/silverlight/ is the correct URL for the SDK.

As far as the ESRI vs Bing discussion, that is subjective. What kind of app are you looking to build? Is this an internal app or a publicly accessible application?

Comment: It is an internal business app. The map integration is not crucial, but will add additional value/information for users. Right now i am leaning towards Bing Maps.

Comment: You might want to check out the license agreement: http://www.microsoft.com/maps/product/licensing.aspx I don't think you can use Bing in an internal application.